# What is the idiomatic way to create a Vec of a specific data type using the vec macro?

Tags: rust

Something like `let v = vec![1, 2, 3];` would default to `i32` but I would like to specify the type as `u8`.

One alternate is to create with:

```
let v: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

or

```
let v: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
v.push(1);
v.push(2);
v.push(3);
```

Is there a better way to directly use the macro? In both cases, I need to declare a variable.

Sometimes, I need to use the vector in an `assert` statement. If there was a way to avoid creating the variable, I could have written:

```
pub fn func1() -> &[u8] {
  // return slice [1, 2, 3] of [u8];
}
assert_eq!(vec![1, 2, 3], func1());
```

Comment: You could easily define your own macro for `let v = tvec![u8; 1, 2, 3];`

Comment: `pub fn func1() -> &[u8]` isn't valid, either.

Comment: The [code you say doesn't work seems to work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=62565f58e34637ca58169ad88976aaf4), so it's not clear what the root problem is.

Comment: @DenysSéguret - How does the custom macro work?

Comment: @VikasGoel `macro_rules!`, especially for straightforward codes like this, are simple enough so you should look at them, but in your specific case you should simple do as  Ikolbly's suggests: `vec![1u8, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type of the vector will be automatically deduced in that situation. This compiles fine:

```rust
fn func1() -> Vec<u8> {
    vec![1, 2, 3]
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(func1(), vec![1, 2, 3]);
}
```

if you need to explicitly specify the type, you can do something like `vec![1u8, 2, 3]`

Comment: Can you expand your answer to address why this is "the idiomatic way", as the OP requested?

Comment: That's a good question, actually I cannot. I've never considered that there may be other ways to do it (for this specific situation with assert_eq).

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not sure about the idiomacy of the way, I'd propose

```
vec![1, 2, 3] as Vec<u8>
```

or just define a macro as suggested:

```
macro_rules! tvec [
    ($t:ty; $($e:expr),*) => { vec![$($e as $t),*] as Vec<$t> }
];
```

and use it like `tvec![u8; 1, 2, 3]`
This works for empty vectors as well.
Here's a [playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f65c2bcd59f84b4375b29c1bae0e7b9c)